# error Unable to get property 'display' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">

    function dropOrderDropDown() {
        var currentInThisElement = document.activeElement.id
        var currentInThisElementArray = currentInThisElement.split('_')
        var foundOneToDrop = false;
        var haveOneCurrentSelected = false;
        var dropDownTempArray = new Array();
        if ((dropDownDivValuesString != "") || (dropDownDivValuesString != null)){
            dropDownTempArray = dropDownDivValuesString.split(',');
            for (i=0; i < dropDownTempArray.length - 1; i++){
                if (acdf != dropDownTempArray[i]){
                    if (document.all[dropDownTempArray[i] + "_hideThisControl"] != null){
                        if (document.all[dropDownTempArray[i] + "_hideThisControl"].style.display != "none"){
                            if (document.all[dropDownTempArray[i] + "_dropdown"] != null){
                                if (document.all[dropDownTempArray[i] + "_dropdown"].style.display == "block"){
                                    document.all[dropDownTempArray[i] + '_txtValue'].click();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        acdf = "";  
        return true;
</script>
```

Comment: Obviously, the style property in one the these lines is null or undefined: document.all[dropDownTempArray[i] + "_hideThisControl"].style.display   or   if (document.all[dropDownTempArray[i] + "_dropdown"].style.display

Comment: But am out of solution, no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using `getElementById()` over `document.all`. `document.all` has limited browser support. Then, bear in mind that `style` only gets inline style properties. So if you aren't declaring style inline, you won't get any results.

Let me know if your issues persist!

Comment: This is already used in the application, i didn't made any changes. So why is this sudden happening

Comment: Add this property to those elements: `style='display:WHATEVER;'`. See if that doesnt stop the javascript errors.

Comment: Am using an array, for that how can I use document .getElementById and am not using inline style sheet

Comment: Where do i need to add this style attribute? can you show me with a sentence

Comment: `<div id="something_hideThisControl" style="display:WHATEVER;"></div>`

Whatever element has the id `something_hideThisControl`

Comment: Thanks for your time, wish I would get a solution

Comment: To clarify, when you say it didnt work, are you still seeing console errors or the script is running into logic errors now?